# Programmatically bundling Nuxt.js application

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am newish to Nuxt world so I will try to describe what I need and what I was failing to do.

I am trying to programmatically build Nuxt application, bundle it and to mount it to a route

```
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt');
const options = require('./nuxt.config.js');

const nuxt = new Nuxt(options);

try {
  await new Builder(nuxt).build();
} catch(error) {
  logger.error('Error building');
  logger.log({ level: 'error', message: error });  
}
```

So what I am interested in is programmatically controlling on how my Nuxt application will be bundled. That should not be an issue since my app is aware of their environment during build time.

So for production environment I would like to load everything bundled and minified/uglified and what else... So if possible I would like to load all html stuff + 1 JS file + 1 css file.

my example config file is

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
       // I should put something here
    }
  },
  srcDir: 'app/view/',
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],
  head: {
    script: [
      { rel: 'preload', src: `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2&appId=${facebookAppId}&autoLogAppEvents=1` }
    ],
    meta: [
    ]
  },
  axios: {
    port: 3010
  },
 router: {
    middleware: [ /*my middlewares*/ ]
  }
};
```

So the question is how can I control build in order to achieve what I want? Bonus point for me would be if I managed to load  scripts  from head.script and merge it to bundle.js file

Comment: its not possible now if i understand you right. You still will have .nuxt folder with files. And you will need node_modules too ( although there is standalone mode where all node modules bundled  in upcoming nuxt 2.3.4 )

Comment: I get that - no problems there. However can I minimize the bundle at least? JS files that are being loaded are not minified at all

Comment: They are minimized by default. Unless u specifically disable it

Comment: I'm afraid they are not. HTML is minimized but when I click to the linked js files they are quite readable....

Comment: Do u have set NODE_ENV=production?

Comment: No. That might be a solution for me.  However the question was - can I control that programmatically? If no - could you tell me what NODE_ENV options are supported?